# Weird visitor from Samara ----forum.topic5982...908.darodar.com?

Tags: spam

I have seen this question asked about a user from Samara,Russia, and when I sifted through all the other occurances,everything everyone else is experiencing matched my experience, except for one thing. The number of visits. In one week the visits to my site from this one user are around 174, all from Samara, or another place that begins with a U inside Russia.  So other people were saying referring spam and whatnot, but this many visits? Also, the name of my business is Puppet Regime. So I am wondering if we are actually being monitored politically in some way. I have no political agenda, I actually make puppets, but I guess if I were a paranoid country I might take a look at a site that uses that phrase. Is there some way to stop the visits?

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking or what the problem is. Your web access logs show someone from Russia visiting your site and you want to block that country?

Answer (score 3):

I am pretty sure that this is (as you already figured out) just regular referrer spam.

The "huge" number of visits makes sure that the referrer appears near the top of the referrer lists in you favorite analytics tool or you spot it in a manual analysis of the logs.
So no, this is not an extraordinary high number of visits but fairly normal. So it is highly unlikely that this is a manual monitoring process that masks as referrer spam.

There are ways to stop these kinds of visits (like blocking IP ranges) but these will certainly block regular users at some point.
I would not bother making extensive changes since your time might be spent better at some other point. If it bothers you, you might want to filter them out of you statistics.
Regarding ways to block IPs or filter certain users out of e.g. Google Analytics you will find a number of posts on this site.